# What is the small glass vessel with a brass cap and handle that is next to tabernacles in some churches?

Tags: catholicism

In this [video](https://youtu.be/RDtJrLwXLWo?t=121) you can see what I'm talking about at the linked timestamp right next to the hand sanitizer.

[image: Jar with brass lid and cross handle on top.]

I've also seen this same little vessel right next to the tabernacle on the same level, instead of on the "front" level. It's harder to tell from the angle in the video, but I usually have seen it with a "handle" on top that's L shaped.

What is it for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called an [ablution cup](https://shop.catholicsupply.com/store/c/2728-Ablution-Cups.aspx):

[image]

It's a vessel of water the priest uses to purify his fingers of the Sacred Particles after he touches a consecrated Host outside of Mass—e.g., after he obtains Hosts to place them in a [pyx](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=35927) for sick calls, or after he distributes Communion outside of Mass. The priest submerges his fingers in the water and makes sure all the Sacred Particles are dissolved—similar to the [ablutions](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=31579) ceremony at the end of Mass, where an altar server pours water over the priest's fingers into the chalice. He then dries his fingers with a [purificator](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=35918).